# GetMapping and PostMapping

Tags: spring-boot, rest, post, get, spring-restcontroller

```java
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @GetMapping(path="/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello-World";
    }
}
```

I am new to RestFul WebServices. I tried to annotate the helloWorld() with PostMapping but it failed. Using GetMapping, it successfully gets executed.

Can somebody tell me why PostMapping was not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

`PostMapping` for POST request.

`GetMapping` for GET request.

If you want call PostMapping success, you can use Postman or SoapUI, curl for testing HTTP POST request.

Reference document:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html

Comment: Can we use Post Request instead of GET request? Can we use them in each other place? Will it make any difference ?

Comment: Of course, you can use GET or POST. But it is different in behavior at client side. For example, you need trigger POST request from a submit button's action.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Do Nhu Vys answer. You will often encounter problems with CORS and CRFS while performing Post Requests.

References:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework